# Is there a way to cut an audio file, from terminal, by the markers inside a WAV file?

Tags: terminal, audio, sox

I have to voice over 1000 words and each one must be saved to an independent audio file.

I am using a microphone attached to the Zoom H5 recorder.

Instead of recording 1000 words individually I intend to record dozens of words at once and add markers between them. Zoom Recorder allows me to add these markers to the wav file and these are seen later in an audio editor like the `01`, `02`, `03`, in the following picture:

[image]

Is there a way to split the audio file, from terminal, using something like `sox` or similar, using the marks?

Comment: you should try to tag a question with the application you use for recording. As far as i know, `WAV` format do no have a "markers".